# HTML Template Editing - responsive

Tags: html, templates, editing

I am currently working and editing this template:

https://freewebsitetemplates.com/preview/rehabilitation-yoga/contact.html

As you can see, on the home page you have to use your mouse to scroll down in order to see the entire content - I want to remove this option and have all the content be displayed and fitted on the entire browser(even if you resize your browser) when you open the page.

I am sorry if this is a "stupid" question - Still pretty much new to all this, so I would be glad to get some help.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is a stupid question, in that you have no control over the size of the user's screen. How will you be sure that there is always room for all content on one screen?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change places of all parts of your content. Change  size and align them properly

Comment: No. You try, and when you can't figure out something specific, then you can ask us to help. We won't write your code for you. Also see my other comment.